# When opening file in default dialog and searching, how to sort by Modified?

Tags: files, gtk

When I open default file choose dialog (in gtk), files are properly sorted by modified date descending. I start typing "yaml", because I want to see only yaml files, but sort order changes to name and it is not possible to click on Modified to change the sort order. I would like to have it sorted by Modified/Descending even in search window. How to do it? There is no such settings in gtk config.

Ubuntu 20.4

Steps:

1. Open text editor
2. Press Ctrl-O to open new file
3. Type "txt" without quotes to search for txt files

Result is not sorted by anything (most likely by folder - name). Is it possible to sort by Modified Descending like in Windows Explorer?

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using? Please explain this excerpt from your question.  When I open default file choose dialog What application is being used?

Comment: I have updated original post with steps to reproduce